# http.get - Wait until file has been generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, http, download

I'm using a [webservice](http://html2pdf.it/) to generate a PDF from a url. I then want to save the generated file to the filesystem. The problem is, that the saved document is empty. This might be, because `http.get` doesn't wait until the file has been generated.
How can I wait for the generated file?

```
var url, writeStream;

writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(dirPath, type + ".pdf"));

url = "http://html2pdf.it?url=" + (encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.com/'));

http.get(url, function(res) {
  res.pipe(writeStream);
  writeStream.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Path:', path.join(dirPath, type + ".pdf"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your webservice returns you a `301` return code (redirects you to another page), and node's `http.get()` just stops there.

You should use a higher level wrapper like [request](https://github.com/request/request) that is easier to use and will actually do what you really want.

Note that you could have found out that yourself by console.logging the `res` from the request:

```
http.get(url, function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  // ...
});
```